# How can I create a list of weeks in access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

How do I create a query which breaks down a frequency of counts based on a list of weeks between 2 different dates in Access?

At the moment I have the following code in t-sql, but would like to have it run in Access.

```
declare @fromdate smalldatetime
declare @todate smalldatetime
declare @toptr smalldatetime
declare @fromptr smalldatetime

set @fromdate  = '1/11/2010'
set @todate  = '27/12/2010'

set @fromptr = dateadd(dd,1 - datepart(weekday,@fromdate), @fromdate)

while @fromptr < @todate
begin   
    print 'from: ' + cast(@fromptr as nvarchar) + ' --> ' + cast(@toptr as nvarchar)
    set @fromptr = dateadd(dd,7, @fromptr)  
    set @toptr =  dateadd(dd,7, @fromptr)
    insert into @weeks values (@fromptr, @toptr)
end
```

I want to somehow bind some rows with lots of dates in them and aggregate them per 'week- ending date' from the dates creating in the table variable.  Access doesn't seem to allow this kind of sql query, so was wondering if there was another way of doing this:
1) either by not using an intermediate table at all, 2) and/or converting the above code into access compatible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will group by week (starting with Sunday) and be faster than other date calculation methods like DateAdd, DateDiff, DatePart, and Format.

```
SELECT
   CDate((([DateColumn] - 1) \ 7) * 7 + 1) AS WeekStartingDate,
   Sum([OrderCount]) AS SumOfOrders
FROM
   Orders
GROUP BY
   CDate((([DateColumn] - 1) \ 7) * 7 + 1);
```

If you want to see week ending date, add 7 at the end instead of 1. The GROUP BY expression can probably be just `([DateColumn] - 1) \ 7` but I'm not sure.

The backslash performs integer division, dividing by 7 converts a week of dates to a single integer, and the -1 adjusts for the fact that the "zero date" is a Saturday rather than a Sunday. To use a different starting day of the week, adjust the -1 and +1 by the same amount. To use Monday, for example, it would be -2 and +2.

This is language and region independent by depending on VB's internal representation of dates as numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Format in Access queries: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa159657(v=office.10).aspx

```
SELECT Format(Date,"ww") FROM Table
GROUP BY Format(Date,"ww")
```

Comment: I would use Format(FromDate, "yyyy-ww")

Answer (score 0):

The plain-vanilla solution is to introduce a `Calendar` table which may look something like

```
Calendar
------------------------
FullDate           date
CalendarYear       integer
DayNumberInWeek    integer
DayNumberInMonth   integer
DayNumberInYear    integer
DayNumberInEpoch   integer
WeekNumberInYear   integer
WeekNumberInEpoch  integer
MonthNumberInYear  integer
MonthNumberInEpoch integer
... and many more that you may need to group by
```

Then if you have table Counters

```
Counters
-----------
FullDate  date
Value     integer  -- cumulative for one day
```

You can:

```
select
    WeekNumberInYear
  , sum(Value)
from Calendar   as a
join Counters   as b on b.FullDate = a.FullDate
where CalendarYear = 2010
group by WeekNumberInYear ;
```

The easiest way to populate the `Calendar` is to spend some time in Excel, create 10-20 years worth of rows and simply import in a DB.

Nothing specific to Access here, but hope you get the idea.

Comment: Format will return pretty nearly every one of these, so why go to this trouble? A calendar showing holidays can be useful, but not, I think so many easily generated groups.

Comment: @Remou, yes some initial trouble -- after that there is no more trouble with date-manipulation. The advantage is that it removes any funny-date-manipulation functions from the WHERE clause which usually force row-by-row processing. The space needed for ~20 years and 45 columns (date-properties) is about 0.006 GB.